# How to specify a read timeout for a Net::HTTP::Post.new request in Ruby 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a post happening to a rails application from a ruby script. The script creates a variable request as

```
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
```

which is then used as follows

```
request.content_type = "application/json"    
request.body =  JSON.generate( params )

response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http| http.request(request)}
```

There is quite a lot of processing happening on the server side, and I'm getting a `Net::ReadTimeout` error

I tried to specify a timeout period

```
request.read_timeout = 500
```

as per [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011387/rescue-in-rbuf-fill-timeouterror-timeouterror) but I got a

```
undefined method `read_timeout=' for #<Net::HTTP::Post POST> (NoMethodError)
```

error. I assume that I'm missing something simple somewhere. All clues gratefully received

Technical info:

- Ruby 2.0.0p247
- Rails 4.0.0
- Windows 7 32 bit ruby

Comment: possible duplicate of [Net::HTTP get timeout in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325479/nethttp-get-timeout-in-ruby) Also for `.new`, post and get should be the same.

Comment: @CiroSantilli that question doesn't have an accepted answer. This one does, albeit my own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set read\_timeout for the service call in Ruby Net::HTTP.start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157553/set-read-timeout-for-the-service-call-in-ruby-nethttp-start)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Solved via this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157553/set-read-timeout-for-the-service-call-in-ruby-nethttp-start)

I've changed my

```
response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http| http.request(request)}
```

line to be

```
response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port, :read_timeout => 500) {|http| http.request(request)}
```

and this seems to have got around this problem.

Comment: If it's posting, seems like write_timeout would make sense. :)

Comment: What about a HTTP.get?

Answer (score 35):

The `read_timeout` is available with a plain `Net::HTTP` object:

```
url = URI.parse('http://google.com')

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.read_timeout = 5 # seconds

http.request_post(url.path, JSON.generate(params)) do |response|
  # do something with response
  p response
end
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind is that if `read_timeout` is set to a small value such that a timeout *does* occur...`Net::HTTP` will "helpfully" retry the request.  For a slow HTTP server, a timeout error may not be raised to the code calling `Net::HTTP` until *2x* the `read_timeout` value.

This certainly was not the behavior I expected.

More info on this topic and how possible solutions differ for Ruby < 2.5 and >= 2.5 may be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59186209/5299483

Answer (score 1):

I catch both OpenTimeout and ReadTimeout and it's work. **test in Ruby:2.6.5**

```rb
def ping(host, port)
    begin
        url = URI.parse("http://#{host}:#{port}/ping")
        req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)

        # setting both OpenTimeout and ReadTimeout
        res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port, :open_timeout => 3, :read_timeout => 3) {|http|
          http.request(req)
        }

        if JSON.parse(res.body)["ok"]
          # return true
          STDERR.puts "#{host}:#{port} is reachable"
        else
          STDERR.puts "#{host}:#{port} is NOT reachable"
        end
    rescue Net::ReadTimeout => exception
        STDERR.puts "#{host}:#{port} is NOT reachable (ReadTimeout)"
    rescue Net::OpenTimeout => exception
        STDERR.puts "#{host}:#{port} is NOT reachable (OpenTimeout)"
    end

end

ping("#{ENV['FIRST_HOST']}", 2345)
ping("#{ENV['SECOND_HOST']}", 2345)
```

Answer (score -8):

If anyone is still facing timeout setting issue and `Net::HTTP` timeout not working as expected, then you may follow below approach as well:

```
begin
    Timeout::timeout(10) {
        ####
        ## YOUR REQUEST CODE WILL BE HERE
        ####
    }
rescue
    408
end
```

Comment: You should be aware that `Timeout` uses threads and you need to be aware of [the implications of that](http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/).

Comment: Ruby’s Timeout is a giant hammer and will only lead to a big mess. Don’t use it. http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/