# Set custom timeout in Net::HTTP::Get.new with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using this code to scraping external html files

> ```
> link = URI.parse(url)
> request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(link.path)
> response = Net::HTTP.start(link.host, link.port) {|http|
>   http.request(request)
> }
> ```

Works great but with slowed web pages sometimes responds timeout, so I need set a timeout limit per connection. Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify a read timeout for a Net::HTTP::Post.new request in Ruby 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547184/how-to-specify-a-read-timeout-for-a-nethttppost-new-request-in-ruby-2) same for get and post

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set the read_timeout attribute.

```
link = URI.parse(url)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(link.path)
begin
  response = Net::HTTP.start(link.host, link.port) {|http|
    http.read_timeout = 100 #Default is 60 seconds
    http.request(request)
  }
rescue Net::ReadTimeout => e  
   puts e.message
end
```

Comment: Works!, perfect but now I need a response to return `false`or `true`depends of the timeout's response. Like `if response = not responding then return false` You know?

Comment: You need to handle the timeout exception. I have made changes to handle the exception in case of timeout.

Comment: And if you think the answer was satisfactory enough, please remember to tick the answer correct :).

Comment: Just one word: awesome. Thank man. Of course I will mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Btw! Ruby 2 are changed this parameters: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#open_timeout-attribute-method

I'll update your reply :D

Comment: I'm simply using Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(s)) - everything in one line. Anyway I can add a time out parameter?