# Preventing timeout when connecting to a URL

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8

I want to see the time taken to access a url using `Benchmark` in the code below. I also tried to do the same thing without benchmark. That is, get time at start of test and end of test, subtract the two to get the time. Both methods end in the same timeout error.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'benchmark'

response = nil
puts "opening website with benchmark..."
puts Benchmark.measure{
  response = open('http://mywebsite.com')
}

puts "Done !"
status = response.status
puts status
```

Error:

```
opening website with benchmark...
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:64:in `rbuf_fill': execution expired (Timeout::Error)
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2028:in `read_status_line'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2017:in `read_new'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1051:in `request'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:248:in `open_http'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:543:in `start'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:242:in `open_http'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:616:in `buffer_open'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:164:in `open_loop'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:162:in `catch'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:162:in `open_loop'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:132:in `open_uri'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:518:in `open'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:30:in `open'
    from C:/code/test.rb:7
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
    from C:/code/test.rb:6
```

When I try to connect to this URL in my browser, it takes about 2-3 minutes to access, all the time.

I searched google, but found no useful answers to my problem. I know that I have to 
change the timeout setting for something, but not able to figure out which one. Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the `:read_timeout` option, specified in seconds, e.g.,

```
open('foo.com', :read_timeout => 10)
```

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/OpenRead.html

Comment: Thanks. How do I set the timeout to infinity ? Could not get that answer quickly from the link you gave. time out = -1 ???

Comment: I am getting the error - `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
response = open(url, read_timeout: 300)`

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev ... You should probably use the correct map syntax for your Ruby version then. I'll edit my answer, but being able to extrapolate from code samples is a valuable skill.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I just realized that I cannot use that argument because i have ruby 1.8. Is there an alternative for this ? Thanks. Error - `check_options': unrecognized option: read_timeout (ArgumentError)`

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Oy, I mis-read which version I was on when I was comparing versions--my fault! Will delete answer--sorry about that.

Comment: No, please don'tdelete the answer. It is still useful as a reference.

Comment: I ended up using ruby 2.x for this. Did not try 1.8 though.

Answer (score 4):

The `BufferedIO` class that `Net::HTTP` uses for the connection that `open-uri` then uses for the request has a [`read_timeout` attribute set to 60 seconds](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_8_7/lib/net/protocol.rb#L52).

The `Net::HTTP` class provides a [setter `read_timeout` for that](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_8_7/lib/net/http.rb#L510).

Unfortunately, the way `open-uri` [sets up](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_8_7/lib/open-uri.rb#L243) that request doesn't provide you with a way to get at that setting before the request or the easily override the default of `60`.

You will probably need to use `Net::HTTP` yourself.

```
link = URI.parse(url)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(link.path)
response = Net::HTTP.start(link.host, link.port) {|http|
  http.read_timeout = 100 #Default is 60 seconds
  http.request(request)
}
```

Code stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20959612/1318694)

edit: or upgrade to 1.9 which supports the `:read_timeout = x` option Dave Newton noted.