# Open-Uri hanging/timing out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, nokogiri, open-uri

I am trying to use open-uri with Nokogiri

```
class Script

  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'open-uri'

  open("http://www.ruby-lang.org/") {|f|
    f.each_line {|line| p line}
  }

end
```

It is timing out with the following error

```
   in `initialize': execution expired (Net::OpenTimeout)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Did you try setting a timeout as explained here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066496/preventing-timeout-when-connecting-to-a-url

Comment: Not sure how that would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The page you try to retrieve take time-out. It could be the slow response of the server which can be adjusted like below, or the site down.

```
            url_object = open(url,  "ssl_verify_mode"=>0, "allow_redirections"=>:safe, "read_timeout"=>Max_http_timeout/1000)
```

Refer to the doc for more explanation: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/OpenURI/OpenRead.html