# Ruby - timeout not working

Tags: ruby, timeout

I'm expecting this piece of code to run for no longer than 5 seconds:

```
require 'httpi'
require 'timeout'

puts Time.new
begin
    request,response=nil,nil
    Timeout::timeout(5){
        request=HTTPI::Request.new(url: "http://example.com")
        response=HTTPI.get(request)
    }
rescue 
    puts "except: #{$!}"
ensure
    puts Time.new
end
```

But this is the output I'm getting:

```
2016-11-04 09:44:55 -0400
D, [2016-11-04T09:44:55.916557 #2476] DEBUG -- : HTTPI GET request to example.com (net_http)
except: execution expired
2016-11-04 09:45:16 -0400
```

I'm assuming NET's default HTTP timeout is 20 seconds, so Timeout::timeout is just allowing the code to run however long it wants. Why?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547184/how-to-specify-a-read-timeout-for-a-nethttppost-new-request-in-ruby-2), [here](http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/) and [here](http://blog.headius.com/2008/02/rubys-threadraise-threadkill-timeoutrb.html), the Ruby's `Timeout` module is famous for having some problems.

You should consider not using this module, unless it is *extremely* necessary.

Instead, you can use the `read_timeout` and/or `open_timeout` options provided by the HTTPI's API.

```
request = HTTPI::Request.new(url: "http://example.com")
request.open_timeout = 5 # seconds
request.read_timeout = 5 # seconds
response = HTTPI.get(request)
```